# Phplot draw image and save it in file

Tags: php, phplot

I try to show image on my page and save it to file .
My code is:

```
//Define the object
$plot = new PHPlot(400,400,'res.png');
$plot->SetIsInline(True);
//Define some data
$example_data = array(
array('a',3),
array('b',5),
array('c',7),
array('d',8),
array('e',2),
array('f',6),
array('g',7)
);
$plot->SetDataValues($example_data);
//Turn off X axis ticks and labels because they get in the way:
$plot->SetXTickLabelPos('none');
$plot->SetXTickPos('none');
//Draw it
$plot->DrawGraph();
```

And I try to call it on html:

```
<img src="image.php">
```

But it olnly save my image to ouput file and doesn't show it in browser.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line of your code into:

```
$plot = new PHPlot(400,400);
```

Answer (score 0):

To save image on server just add these 2 lines before $plog->DrawGraph() call

```
$plot->SetIsInline(true);
$plot->SetOutputFile('image.png');
```

Then you can use in html:

```
<img src="image.png">
```